# Convert string with a mix of numbers and letters to a number

Tags: go

I'm having trouble converting a string with mixed letters and and numbers to a number with (or without) decimals. The string isn't necessarily `99,50`, but could also be any other string represented number. The decimal separator could also be `.` instead of `,`.

I've tried the following ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/4-uAcN7VxPU)):

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    price := "99,50 SEK"

    res1, _ := strconv.Atoi(price)
    fmt.Println(res1)

    res2, _ := strconv.ParseInt(price, 10, 64)
    fmt.Println(res2)

    res3, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(price, 64)
    fmt.Println(res3)
}
```

The output I get from all of them is this:

```
0
```

The output I **want** is this:

```
99.50
```

Also acceptable would be:

```
99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp` package for remove letters and replace `,` with `.` using  `ReplaceAll` and parse

```
price := "99,50 SEK"    
reg, _:= regexp.Compile("[^0-9,]+") // regex for digit and comma only
processedString := reg.ReplaceAllString(price , "") // remove all letters 
processedString = strings.ReplaceAll(processedString, ",", ".") // replace comma with point

res3, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(processedString, 64)
```

Code in Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/9sD0F_gCfJN)

Comment: I would even suggest to use `(\d+),(\d+)` and use `reg.FindAllSubmatch..` to directly extract the numbers.

Comment: @ifnotak problem is `,` and float value need to parse